# C#: I created a SpanishTranslate method using a switch statement but it won't work in my Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, debugging, methods, switch-statement

So, here's the gist, we were given an assignment to create two methods aside from the methods (DisplayNumbers,FindSum,ProductSum,CreateRandomNumber) that were already given. I was tasked with creating a CompareInteger method that compared the numbers and stated which one is greater. The other is TranslateSpanish where I changed the number into the Spanish word (Ex: 7 = Siete) and type it out stating "the numbers in Spanish are {spanish number} and {spanish number}.
-The issue is that whenever I try to print "the numbers in Spanish are {method} and {method} it still prints the numbers and not the words, but if I call the method outside of the console.writeline it works

Now it was recommended to complete the first method (CompareIntegers) using and if statement and the second method (TranslateSpanish) using a switch statement.

I've tried writing it in different way and I dont want to cheat by calling the methods on different lines from the console.writeline.

```
using System.Net;

class M9Methods
{
    static Random randomNumber = new Random();
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num1, num2;
        // Call method to create a random number and store in variable num1
        num1 = CreateRandomNumber();
        // Call method to create a random number and store in variable num2
        num2 = CreateRandomNumber();

    
        DisplayNumbers(num1, num2); // Call method to display the numbers
                                    // Call method to find the sum and display the result.
        Console.WriteLine($"The sum of {num1} and {num2} is {FindSum(num1, num2)}");
        // Call method to find the product and display result.
        Console.WriteLine($"The product of {num1} and {num2} is {FindProduct(num1, num2)}");
        // Call method that compares the numbers and tells which is largest or if they are equal.
        Console.WriteLine($"The largest number between {num1} and {num2} is {CompareInteger(num1, num2)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The {num1} and {num2} in spanish are {TranslateSpanish1(num1)}");
    
    }
    // Method to create a random integer from 1 to 10 and return it
    public static int CreateRandomNumber()
    {
        int num = randomNumber.Next(10) + 1; // Create a random number from 1 to 10
        return num;
    }
    // Method to display 2 integers
    public static void DisplayNumbers(int n1, int n2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The first number is {n1}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The second number is {n2}");
    }
    // Method to return the sum of 2 integers
    public static int FindSum(int n1, int n2)
    {
        return n1 + n2;
    }
    // Method to return the product of 2 integers
    public static int FindProduct(int n1, int n2)
    {
        return n1 * n2;
    }
    // Method to compare 2 integers and display which is largest or if they are equal
    public static int CompareInteger(int n1, int n2)
    {

        if (n1 > n2)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine($"The largest number is: {n1}");
            return n1;
        }
        else if (n1 == n2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"These are the same numbers, Theyre equal!");
            return n1;
        }
        else
        {
           // Console.WriteLine($"The largest number is: {n2} ");
            return n2;
        }
    }
    // Method to return/display the number in Spanish.
    public static int TranslateSpanish1(int n1)
    {
            switch (n1)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Uno");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Dos");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Tres");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Quatro");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cinco");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine("Seis");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Console.WriteLine("Siete");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ocho");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Console.WriteLine("Nueve");
                    break;
                case 10:
                    Console.WriteLine("Diez");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("couldnt comprehend");
                    break;
            }

        
        return n1;

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to debug your code. You need to do that BEFORE posting here. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn that first. Set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, examining the state at each step. As soon as the state does not meet your expectations, you've found an issue and you can focus on that specifically. If you don't know how to fix it, you can tell us EXACTLY where and how the code behaves other than as expected.

Comment: The way you use your function here `Console.WriteLine($"The {num1} and {num2} in spanish are {TranslateSpanish1(num1)}");` makes it look like you expect it will return a string that you can print. It doesn't, it just writes directly to the console and returns the integer passed in., so maybe return the string instead. You might consider a line of whitespace every once in a while. It'll make your code a lot easier to read.

Comment: What we see here is the result of writing code without knowing what it has to do. That means knowing not only the end result but the steps to get there. If you spent time to work out the logic first and then write code to implement that logic, it's unlikely that you'd end up with that code.

Comment: One immediate clue that something is wrong would be the fact that the purpose of that translation method is to convert a number to text, yet the parameter is type `int` and the return type is also type `int`. How could text be returned as type `int`? That is something you should be able to spot when you compare your logic to your code, which is why you need to actually have that logic worked out.

Comment: Actually another example of poor _teaching_... if the instructions are _that_ microspecific and need to be, then it would have been better to first examine some example code which demonstrates 'if' and 'switch' uses, first. And the fact that it can still be messed up shows the lack of prior basics.

Comment: @Fildor, I agree that, if you're going to have to use `if` and `switch` in an assignment then you need to be taught how they work but this question provides no specific evidence that that wasn't done. That the student got it wrong doesn't mean that they weren't taught what they need to know to get it right. I know that from my own personal experience.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I partly agree. But from my experience of the last couple years specifically, there seem to be very few teachers that can bring _real beginners_ up to a level where they can strive on their own after being shown a certain concept or pattern or syntaxes.